# How to manually stop kestrel server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am doing this basic tutorial: http://www.asp.net/get-started
It suggests doing some changes, then running `dotnet run` again. However, Ctrl+C isn't working and the Package Manager Console seems frozen. When I exit VS and/or restart it, I do my changes and `dotnet run` again.
When I am doing this, I am getting an error (not the same every time), because the server is already running. The question is simple as 1-2-3:
How do I manually stop the kestrel server? (I am running Windows 10).

Comment: If you ran from the command line: Ctrl + C

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I forgot to mention that doesn't work! Also, when I quit VS and/or restart it, the process still runs (page refreshes on Chrome)! Where do I find the relevant process and how do I kill it? I will Update the Q with extra info...Thanx!

Comment: Related [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306332/stop-a-running-dotnet-core-website-running-on-kestrel). This is currently an issue with the cli [terminating `dotnet run` doesn't terminate child #7426](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7426)

Answer (score 37):

On OSX Terminal:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep :5000
```

[image]

```
sudo kill -9 1872
```

Answer (score 31):

I ran this on powershell to kill all instances of the kestral server

```
Get-Process -Name *dotnet* | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thank you - works a treat! (In Windows/VS Terminal too)

Answer (score 9):

For windows users:

Run `netstat -ano -p TCP | find /I "listening" | find /I "port number"`
then run `taskkill /F /PID process ID` on Command Prompt.

Here is an example

```
C:\Users\Kiran>netstat -ano -p TCP | find /I "listening" | find /I "2492"
TCP    127.0.0.1:2492         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       820

C:\Users\Kiran>taskkill /F /PID 820
SUCCESS: The process with PID 820 has been terminated.
```

Here `netstat -ano -p TCP | find /I "listening" | find /I "2492"` finds the process running TCP protocol listening on port 2492. And `taskkill /F /PID 820` command to forcefully terminate the process with id 820

Comment: You may get : ERROR: The process with PID ... could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied. Run cmd as Administrator.

Answer (score 8):

If anything else fails you can simply close it from the task manager. The name of the process would be **dotnet**. If you have Visual Studio open (in my case at least), there may be at least one other dotnet process running. Could not distinguish between them using only the task manager...

PS: When launching Kestrel with **dotnet run** from the PMC, in the console you get this:

*Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to shut down.*

But it didn't work to stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: I don't see 'dotnet' in my list of tasks even though supposedly Kestrel is holding onto a site running in docker (even though I've fully stopped and removed the docker container)

Answer (score 5):

The line below works for me.

`killall -9 dotnet`

Answer (score 4):

Stumbled upon it today. The answer above looks cool but netstat is slow. A simpler way to kill kestrel would be to use the PowerShell commandlet [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps).

To kill kestrel listening on Port 5000, the command would be

```
$pId = (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 5000).OwningProcess[0]
kill -Id $pId
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the following in a .cmd file and click on the file:

```
Taskkill.exe /F /IM dotnet.exe /T
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> also does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS 12.6 (Monterey) with .NET Core 6 and 7, this command worked for me.

`pgrep -f dotnet | xargs kill -9`