# Stop a running dotnet core website running on kestrel

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

When deploying a new version of an existing .net core website. How do I first **safely** stop the old running kestrel app?

Here is an exmaple of what I would like to write (Pseudo deployment script):

```
dotnet stop mysite/mysite.dll <---- this line here
mv mysite/ mysite.bak/
cp newly-published-mysite/ mysite/
dotnet run mysite/mysite.dll
```

`killall dotnet` seems a little unsafe. How would it work if I were hosting two small sites on one box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have decided to use supervisor to monitor and manage the process. [Here is an excellent article on getting it set up](https://serversforhackers.com/monitoring-processes-with-supervisord).

It allows simple control over specific dotnet apps like this:

```
supervisorctl stop MyWebsiteName
supervisorctl start MyWebsiteName
```

And it has one huge advantage in that it can try restart the process if it falls over, or when the system reboots... for whatever reason.

Answer (score 18):

Accordingly to [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1327), there is no safe way to stop Kestrel now. You need to find a PID by name of your dll and [kill it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510850/5112433):

```
kill $(ps aux | grep 'MySite.dll' | awk '{print $2}')
```

In case of process tree, you need to manually grep all child IDs and call `kill` for each. Like it was done in 
[Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ProcessExtensions.KillTree](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/ffb7c20fb22a31ac31d3a836a8455655867e8e16/shared/Microsoft.Extensions.Process.Sources/ProcessHelper.cs#L22) method (correct link from the discussion).

Comment: Updated link to the issue [terminating `dotnet run` doesn't terminate child](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7426)

Comment: exactly what I wanted for a dev script.  I also found that it was picking up the grep pipe process and added this to remove it (before awk). `| grep -v 'grep'`