# How to properly stop running dotnet core web application?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, kestrel, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 on Windows, I run `dotnet watch run` in the **Package Manager Console**. It launched kestrel for a dotnet core app, automatically disabled text edit in the console, and displayed a red button to stop command execution, but the button doesn't do anything. Also, the message is being displayed to use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> but it doesn't work either.

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:20436 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Now there is an error when I try to launch the web app in Visual Studio because it is already running.
I couldn't find a command like `dotnet stop` only <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>  which doesn't work in this case. I used Process Hacker to kill the `dotnet.exe` process but that doesn't seem right. What would be the best way to kill the running process?

Comment: how are you opening the project on visual studio? did you open a solution or did you open visual studio on the current folder

Comment: i generally either run with debugger or run `dotnet watch run` from command line outside vs

Comment: Double Ctrl+C worked for me in VS2019.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906481/how-to-manually-stop-kestrel-server might be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

---

**run your project:**

dotnet run > Examplelog.log &

`$ dotnet run > Examplelog.log &`

`[1] 162`

---

**end your project:**

kill 162

`$ kill 162`

`[1]+  Exit 127                dotnet run > Examplelog.log`

---

So with kill[id] you can end your process.

you not need a second console and can use your console for other inputs (take note that all outputs will be stored inside the Examplelog.log-File you have to check)^^lg

Answer (score 0):

Since this stop option doesn't work it is clearly a bug. If I need to run `dotnet watch run` I generally just open command line on my current folder outside VS and run it from there. Since `dotnet watch run` has nothing to do with visual studio (no debugging) it makes sense. Alternatively, you can use the green button to run within visual studio with debugger. However, this would mean you can't edit the code while testing.

Comment: Usually for testing I lunch apps normal way F5 or green button, but for being able to see updates on the fly I assumed that one Microsoft product would work flawlessly with another one. Looks like the best option for now is to use command line outside Visual Studio.

Comment: yes, it is supposed to. this seems to be a bug. I never really try doing this from vs

Comment: have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152854/how-to-watch-for-file-changes-dotnet-watch-with-visual-studio-asp-net-core

Comment: It is not a bug you just have to press the stop button :)

Answer (score 0):

when the service is already running just again apply build command "dotnet build" and then again run command apply like "dotnet run"
services will be up again then you just have to press Ctrl+c in the terminal to shutdown running services.

Answer (score -3):

There is a red button next to the clear button in that section next to the project name. I just found it LOL I will show you a picture follow the yellow circle. I was trying ctrl+c too LOL[image]

Comment: as stated in the original question, that button didn't work. I hope it got fixed finally.

Comment: yeah I was having the same issue but that button started working so I no longer had that issue sorry