# How to stop dotnet watch run properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a folder with identity scaffolded dotnet application from the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

After i run `dotnet watch run`, I have an error like this:

```
❯ dotnet watch run
watch : Started
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://127.0.0.1:5001: address already in use.
 ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.AddressInUseException: Address already in use
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (48): Address already in use
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketConnectionListener.Bind()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Apparently my previous dotnet core app that was run through cli and stopped with ctrl + c does not stop. What should I do?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799322/how-to-properly-stop-running-dotnet-core-web-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649979/failed-to-bind-to-address-already-in-use-error-with-visual-studio-mac-api) questions but they did not help. Also opened an issue in dotnet core app, is this a bug? How did everyone stop dotnet core app?

Do I need to stop it from activity monitor everytime?
I saw dotnet service, and also Identity service on my activity monitor. I'm not sure how many service do I need to clear if the cli doesn't clean its own service

Comment: Seems there is already an issue logged here - https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/948

Comment: Yeah and its closed, i opened and issue and referenced that issue too